# VB.NET: How can I use ExecuteSQLCommand and return my data in a datatable and access it?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sqlcommand

This is what I'm trying...

```
Dim myCommand as SqlCommand
Dim myTable as New xsdObject.ObjectDataTable

myCommand = DataAccess.GetSQLCommand( "MyStoredProc", _
                       CommandType.StoredProcedure, SourceServer.ConnectionLocal)

myCommand.Connection.ChangeDatabase("MyDatabase")
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter", DataValue)

ExecuteSQLCommand(myCommand, myTable)

 'How to access my data ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example without the datatable, as mentioned in your comment.

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader= MyCommand.ExecuteReader
    Dim MyList as new List(Of WhateverObject)
    Do While reader.Read
        Dim obj as new WhateverObj
        obj.Property1 = Reader.GetInt32(0)
        obj.Property2 = Reader.GetString(1)
        MyList.add(obj)
    Loop

    reader.Close()
    myCommand.Dispose()
```

For the sake of complete answer that matches the title, with a dataset:

```
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Adapter.Fill(ds)
```

The Datatable:

```
Dim resultTable as DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

To put the results in a `DataTable`, you need to create a `SqlDataAdapter` around the `SqlCommand` and call its `Fill` method.

Comment: I was just thinking... this Sub is in my class file. I don't really need a DataTable I dont think. I just want to input the information from the Stored Procedure into my member variables. So what would I do for that? Still use the SqlDataAdapter and set the SelectCommand to my "myCommand" and then how can I access the data from there?

Comment: If you just want to read the result, you shouldn't use a `DataTable`.  Instead, call `ExecuteReader` on the command to get a DataReader.